# Using a relay to control a lamp

Tags: arduino-uno, relay, automatization

Okay, so I'm using an Arduino Uno R3 and I wanted to start of my own home automation project. I have a 4 channel 12V relay board and I normally connect it to a 12V 500mA adapter. What is the maximum wattage bulb (or CFL) that I can power with this configuration?

Comment: The ampere rating should be printed on the relays. `Watts = Amps x Voltage`

Comment: @Gerben. Thanks for the heads up! It says 5A 240V AC and the coil is 12V DC.

Comment: Than that's 1000Watt if you're on 220V AC, 500Watt if your on 110V AC (e.g. US). Good luck finding a 1000Watt CFL :-P

Answer (score 1):

Unless you feel like starting a fire, none. Find a 220V 2A relay with a 5V coil and use that instead, switching the hot wire and not the neutral.

Comment: Huh? If the OP builds a circuit to switch 12v (with a flyback diode) why would the relay board in question start a fire?

Comment: @DuncanC: There aren't many CFL bulbs that run on 12V, and the asker hadn't given the contact specifications yet.